# rsync whole VM from Azure to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, virtual-machines, rsync, migration

I am trying to move Centos 7 machine from Azure VM to AWS EC2 instance. I have some basic understanding on Linux so i need to your help in resolving what's going on here.

I am using rsync in this case and prior to moving data i built exclusion list which you can find [here](http://www.thunderstrukt.com/files/exclude.txt)

And [here](http://www.thunderstrukt.com/files/rsync1st.txt) you can find log of initial pass of rsync.

Command i use to trigger sync:

```
rsync -e "ssh" -rlpEAXogDtSzh -P -x --exclude-from="$EXCLUDEFILE" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --verbose --progress / centos@$TARGETVM:/
```

Sync goes good, however, after it finishes, target machine drops SSH connections and I am not able to access it anymore by any means (after restart i can see in AWS console it fails to start OpenSSH deamon, and PuTTY is giving me "connection refused" messages), which makes me think I did not exclude everything I should.

Can someone take a look and tell me which important parameters I am overwriting and what I should add to my exclusion list to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, you can not migrate a linux vm using rsync because the content in /etc or /dev will not be the same, you need to create similar vm on aws and then rsync only the user data or specific application and its data .

Comment: Are you sure? i actually have machines with same config (CentOS version, attached disks, etc.). My starting point was this article 
https://cloudnull.io/2012/07/cloud-server-migration/#migrate-using-rsync-the-easy-way

which makes me think it's possible.

Comment: I suggest you migrate your data only. Use an automated build system like AWS Opsworks / Ansible / etc to build the new VM, then bring the data across. Another option is to use S3 as a staging area for data.

Comment: Is there some benefit of using Ansible in this case than creating machine in standard way? I am just moving one machine, it's not batch job.

Comment: I don't think your proposed method could be called a "standard way". IMHO you should install the VM, copy over the files you ned.

Comment: I'd just use Azure Site Recovery for this instead. Way easier and you migrate an exact copy of the VM without having to deal with all this stuff of rsync that will never provide an exact copy anyway.

Comment: Hi, i am moving machine from Azure to AWS so ASR can't help me here.

Comment: You need to skip the SSH authorized_keys directory in the users's home directory.